# py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o51.__getnewargs__. Trace: py4j.Py4JException: Method __getnewargs__([]) does not exist

Tags: python-2.7, pyspark

I am creating a data frame which I will used in later part of code to insert records to hive table, here is the code.

## I am getting following error message with this code

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o51.__getnewargs__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getnewargs__([]) does not exist
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:272)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

===========

```
def fn_create_df_load_status():
   data = sc.parallelize([
    [ ('cust_id', custid)     \
    , ('sys_rec', 'source system')   \
    , ('load_start_ts', (from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))) \
    , ('load_end_ts',   (from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))) \
    , ('status', 'STARTED')]
    ])
# Convert to tuple
   data_converted = data.map(lambda x: (x[0][1]))

# Define schema
   schema = StructType([
       StructField("cust_id", StringType(), True),
       StructField("sys_rec", StringType(), True),
       StructField("load_start_ts", StringType(), True),
       StructField("load_end_ts", StringType(), True),
       StructField("status", StringType(), True)
    ])

# Create dataframe
   DF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data_converted, schema)

# Output
   DF.show()
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the line `('load_start_ts', (f.from_unixtime(f.unix_timestamp(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")))` and the one after it?

Comment: I am trying to get current date and time in "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" format, to insert the entry in to log table

Answer (score 0):

Here is updated code

```
def fn_create_df_load_status():
   from time import gmtime, strftime

   load_start_ts = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
   load_end_ts = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())

   print ("load_start_ts : ", load_start_ts)
   print ("load_end_ts : ", load_end_ts)

   data = sc.parallelize([
    ( ('cust_id', custid)     \
    , ('sys_rec', 'source system') \
    , ('load_start_ts', load_start_ts) \
    , ('load_end_ts',  load_end_ts) \
    , ('status', 'STARTED'))
    ])
# Convert to tuple
   data_converted = data.map(lambda x: (x[0][1], x[1][1], x[2][1], x[3][1], x[4][1]))

# Define schema
   schema = StructType([
       StructField("cust_id", StringType(), True),
       StructField("sys_rec", StringType(), True),
       StructField("load_start_ts", StringType(), True),
       StructField("load_end_ts", StringType(), True),
       StructField("status", StringType(), True)
    ])

# Create dataframe
   DF = spark.createDataFrame(data_converted, schema)

# Output
   DF.show()
```